# "Plug the fan in and switch on at the wall" - meaning of "switch on at the wall"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

From an [instruction page](http://www.dyson.com/support/am03/am03-pedestal-fan-silver/flo-dc07-gen-how-to-use-your-dyson/redirect-to-using-your-dyson-fan-am03/using-your-dyson-fan-am03) to a bladeless fan model:

> Plug the fan in and **switch on at the wall**.

Is there a typo of some sort? What can they mean by "switch on at the wall"?

I know that usually one first plugs in an appliance, and next switches it on. Judging by the picture, the ON/OFF switch is located on the fan's base. Thus it's unclear what they mean by "at the wall".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the United Kingdom, all electrical outlets have switches on them.